# AWS Cloudformation Automatic Backup and Restore Redis CacheCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, backup, persistence

I want to enable automatic backups on my redis cluster on AWS.

Looking at the documentation I have to specify `SnapshotRetentionLimit` and `SnapshotWindow`. This kind of works and it creates the backup for me.

Now the problem is how can I use the latest backup and restore my redis cluster when it's restarted for example ?

I see there's a parameter `SnapshotName`:

> SnapshotName
>   The name of a Redis snapshot from which to restore data into the new node group (shard). The snapshot status changes to restoring while the new node group (shard) is being created.

Which name should I include? Automatic backup creates backups with dynamic names (prefixes them with date and time). Can I somehow get the latest backup name through cloudformation template? Is this even possible via cloudformation template?

Thank you

Comment: Got any answers to this sir?